# How to print PDFsharp PdfDocument object?

Tags: c#, pdf, pdfsharp

PdfDocument class in PDFsharp does not have any type of print method neither does the PDFsharp PdfFilePrinter class ctor's accept any PdfDocument object.

```
ms = new MemoryStream();
using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(path))
{
    fs.CopyTo(ms);
}

document = new PdfDocument();
document = PdfReader.Open(ms);
```

So can anybody provide me solution to print my document object?

Answer (score 0):

PdfFilePrinter just calls Adobe Reader to print the PDF file. So you need a file and cannot pass a PdfDocument.

Judging from your sample code you already have a file. No need to read this file into a PdfDocument object if you only want to print it.